# Form within PrimeNG Template not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

I defined a form within PrimeNG's turbotable. The purpose of the form is to create another entry (a group) to the table located in the footer of the table. Unfortunately it is not displaying. Any idea why?

```
<ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-columns>
      <form [formGroup]="groupForm" (ngSubmit)="createGroup()"> 
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button pButton type="submit" icon="pi pi-plus"
                [disabled]="!groupForm.valid" pTooltip="add group"></button>
          </td>

          <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <input pInputText type="text" [formControlName]="col.field">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </ng-template>
```

col is just an array in component defining some data like column size and the associated field of a group.

The col.field values of course match the control names of the defined FormGroup.

```
groupForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    field1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    //...
  });
```

I want to use form since all the fields are required to create a new group and I thought this is the best way to handle it. If you have a better suggestion feel free to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue. I simply removed the form-tag, instead I attached the formGroup to tr-tag.